# Converting AD TimeStamp with T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to convert Windows NT time from a SQL query pull to a readable format?
I'm doing an AD pull of user accounts and I want to convert or CAST the windows AD timestamp to a better readable format. The issue is I am having problems doing that converting when doing the pull.

Query:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN CHARINDEX('@', userPrincipalName) > 7
      THEN SUBSTRING(userPrincipalName, 1, (CHARINDEX('@', userPrincipalName)) - 1)
    ELSE ''
  END AS edipi
 ,UPPER(samaccountname) AS samaccountname
 ,givenName AS firstName
 ,sn AS lastName
 ,initials
 ,UPPER(mail) AS email
 ,userAccountControl
 ,telephoneNumber
 ,title
 ,accountExpires
FROM
  OPENQUERY
    (ADSI
     ,'select 
          givenName, 
          samaccountName, 
          userPrincipalName, 
          sn, 
          initials, 
          mail, 
          userAccountControl, 
          telephoneNumber, 
          title, 
          accountExpires
        from ''LDAP PATH''
        where objectcategory=''person'' and objectclass = ''user'' and name=''*'' '
    );
```

My query returns the accountExpires Field in windows NT time but, I want it to be something like this:

2020-02-09 15:23:36.367

instead of this:

132257354163700000

I have come up with a simple solution doing the converting one by one, but I want it to do the CAST on the pull instead of having to do this for every users

```
DECLARE @accountExpired BIGINT
SET @accountExpired = 132257354163700000; --This is a random time pulled from a user from the above select statement.

SELECT CAST((@accountExpired / 864000000000.0 - 109207) AS DATETIME);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can't you just wrap your formula around `accountExpires` in your `SELECT` statement?

Comment: No, I cannot I get the error message "Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric."

Comment: Do you know which row in particular is giving you that Arithmetic Overflow error? That row could possibly contain a `NULL` value. You would probably need to check prior to casting that the value is not null.

Comment: A `NULL` numerator will just return a `NULL` in that equation, not an error.

Comment: Yes, Eric, you are correct. I should have mentioned a possibility of having a `0` value on the column itself, instead of `NULL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When SQL Server does an [implicit conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) from `nvarchar` to `numeric` (or *anything* to `numeric`, actually), it sets the default precision and scale to `numeric(18,0)`. That's good enough for the sample data in your question, but the error message indicates that there's a value somewhere in your data set that exceeds the capacity of the defaulted data type.

To get past that, try an explicit cast to a larger capacity `numeric`. Maybe:

```
SELECT
  ...
 ,CAST((CAST(accountExpires AS numeric(28,0)) / 864000000000.0 - 109207) AS DATETIME)
 ...
```

Probably, `numeric(19,0)` would be sufficient, but if you go over 19, you might as well go to 28 since 20-28 all have the same storage size.

Comment: Thanks, but like you said something was up with data. There were AD Accounts that were set to never expire(Big no-no in this OU) which created a longer number causes the issue. Thank you for the help and now to let our AD folks fix their accounts.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me for every user in AD.

```
CAST((convert(bigint, lastlogontimestamp) / 864000000000.0 - 109207) AS DATETIME) as lastLogonTimestamp,
```

> -- To overcome the limit of datetime convert to big or to small to null
> case when convert(bigint, accountexpires) = 0 then null
> when convert(bigint, accountexpires) > 2650467743999999716
> then null else CAST((convert(bigint, accountexpires) / 864000000000.0 - 109207) AS DATETIME) end as accountexpires

Answer (score 1):

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER  FUNCTION [dbo].[filetime_to_datetimeoffset](@file_time BIGINT)
RETURNS DATETIMEOFFSET
WITH INLINE = ON, SCHEMABINDING, RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ns_one_day BIGINT = 864000000000
    DECLARE @ns_one_hr BIGINT = 36000000000
    DECLARE @ns_one_sec BIGINT = 10000000
    DECLARE @ns_one_ms BIGINT = 10000
    DECLARE @ns_one_microsec BIGINT = 10

    DECLARE @days BIGINT = @file_time/@ns_one_day
    SET @file_time = @file_time - (@days * @ns_one_day)

    DECLARE @hrs BIGINT = @file_time/@ns_one_hr
    SET @file_time = @file_time - (@hrs * @ns_one_hr)

    DECLARE @secs BIGINT = @file_time/@ns_one_sec
    SET @file_time = @file_time - (@secs * @ns_one_sec)

    DECLARE @ms BIGINT = @file_time/@ns_one_ms
    SET @file_time = @file_time - (@ms * @ns_one_ms)

    DECLARE @microsec BIGINT = @file_time/@ns_one_microsec
    SET @file_time = @file_time - (@microsec * @ns_one_microsec)

    DECLARE @ns BIGINT = @file_time

    RETURN CASE
        WHEN @file_time IS NULL THEN NULL
        WHEN @file_time < 0 THEN CAST(CAST(CAST('FILETIME cannot be negative.' AS BIT) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS DATETIMEOFFSET)
        ELSE DATEADD(NANOSECOND, @ns, DATEADD(MICROSECOND, @microsec, DATEADD(MILLISECOND, @ms, DATEADD(SECOND, @secs, DATEADD(HOUR, @hrs, DATEADD(DAY, @days, DATETIMEOFFSETFROMPARTS(1601, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7)))))))
    END
END
```

```sql
SELECT dbo.filetime_to_datetimeoffset(999999999999999999)
SELECT dbo.filetime_to_datetimeoffset(0)
SELECT dbo.filetime_to_datetimeoffset(133434285882620000)
```

returns

- 4769-11-16 09:46:39.9999990 +00:00
- 1601-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00
- 2023-11-02 19:56:28.2620000 +00:00

Answer (score 0):

Several years late to the party, but hopefully this helps others trying to query LDAP.

Erics' answer is great! However, I ran into the overflow error and had to increase the NUMERIC(28,0) to NUMERIC(38,0) to account for very large numbers/dates from AD.
The Select statement example below will output "2023-07-15 00:00:00.000"

```
select CAST((CAST(133338528000000000 AS numeric(38,0)) / 864000000000.0 - 109207) AS DATETIME) as accountExpires
```

Below is a working example, on my domain of course, that pulls 500 records from LDAP and converts the accountExpires to a readable date. The userAccountControl statements are for pulling Active and Disabled employees only and excluding accounts without a password.

```
 SELECT TOP 500 [name], adsPath, streetaddress, pager, company, title, displayName, telephoneNumber, sAMAccountName, mail, mobile,facsimileTelephoneNumber, department, physicalDeliveryOfficeName, givenName, cn, initials, mailnickname, othertelephone,ou, postaladdress, l, postalcode, st, C, sn, Manager, userPrincipalName,distinguishedName, userAccountControl,employeeID
,CAST((CAST(accountExpires AS numeric(38,0)) / 864000000000.0 - 109207) AS DATETIME) as accountExpires
FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI,
'<LDAP://MyDomain.com/DC=MyDomain,DC=com>;
(&(employeeNumber=*)(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=512)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=32)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(samAccountType=805306368)(mail=*)(uSNChanged=*));
name,adsPath,streetaddress,pager,company,title,displayName,telephoneNumber,sAMAccountName,mail,mobile
,facsimileTelephoneNumber,department,physicalDeliveryOfficeName,givenName,cn,initials,mailnickname, othertelephone
,ou,postaladdress,l,postalcode,st,C,sn,Manager,userPrincipalName, distinguishedName, userAccountControl,employeeID,accountExpires;subtree')
```

I hope this helps